# How do I fix an internal laptop monitor showing up as unknown connection?

Tags: configuration, laptop, graphics, wubi, monitor

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu and trying it out but installing 10.10 via Wubi on to my old Samsung V25 laptop.

For the larger part, the system seems to be working fine, apart from one key point, its internal monitor is not functional, only output to an external monitor works.

During install and the GUI section of setup, (where the slideshow is displayed, after the Windows part), displayed correctly on the internal monitor, however, after the first reboot, as soon as the Splash screen displays on my external monitor, the internal one shuts off completely. Not blank, it appears entirely turned off.

The graphics card is reported by lspci -nn as an 'Intel Corporation 82845/G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device [8086:2562] (rev 03)'.

With some help of friends, I've run xrandr but it reports LVDS1, the laptop screen as 'Unknown Connection'. Trying to force display through it at a known safe resolution causes the error: "cannot find crtc for output LVDS1"

How can I fix this so I can use the laptop with just its internal monitor rather than having to hook it up to another screen?

**Update:** Having done further searching online, I have now got the system to the point of being able to boot to text mode at 800x600 and, **if an external monitor is connected**, boot in to graphics mode. If the external monitor is not connected, graphics fails to start but I can at least <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to the terminal. To do this, I added `i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa` to the boot instruction. Along with setting `GRUB_GFXMODE` and `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD` to 800x600. And set the Driver in the Device section of xorg.conf to `vesa`.

Now my only requirement is setting the laptop to boot with graphics mode without needing an external monitor connected.

Comment: Does the same happen if start the laptop without the external monitor connected?

Comment: @Source Lab - Without the monitor connected, there is no output from the internal monitor and the machine has to be rebooted before it finds the external monitor.

Comment: What is the RAM size of the machine? If it allows you to run a live Ubuntu CD, would you please try it without connecting the external monitor. In case of memory unsuffiency to run recent live CD, older ones and/or Xubuntu live CD may help. This way, it you can test if Ubuntu -as a standalone OS, not within Windows- sees your internal monitor or not. Then, it might be easier to discuss on some possible approaches. (If to say, I, personally, have no Wubi experience.) Another approach -or the next step- may be installing Ubuntu on a partition of your disk (if you can allocate such a partition).

Comment: *Addition to my previous comment*: The **scenorio** I suspect is as follows: Your Windows installation/settings have elements for both monitors -> Ubuntu via Wubi -for some reason we don't know yet- detected one of them (in this case the external one) -> Own moniter of the machine is unkonwn to Ubuntu at the moment (but Ubuntu has the capability to recognize it and maybe it needs to be connected as a second monitor, from the side of Ubuntu, at the moment) PS: What is the exact model of the machine? Samsung V25 **xxx** ?

Comment: A Google search such as http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Ubuntu+%22Samsung+V25%22+82845G%2FGL&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 gives results related with some problems of your card but many of them seems to have something to do with "fine tuning". Anyway, those reports might be usefull in some way.

Comment: Ram size is 512MB. Considering the system was able to boot in to its installer that users generic drivers, I would guess without having to go to the trouble of burning a CD, that it would work too. I will update the question with some further configuration changes I made that got me part of the way there.

Comment: As you are getting further with KMS disabled the resolution of the internal display is likely not being correctly determined.  You should file a bug against the Linux Kernel in Launchpad.  From a terminal window use the command 'ubuntu-bug linux' that will get us the information we need to better diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly report this issue as a bug if you're still being effected by it, from a command line (Applications > Accessories > Terminal) copy and paste the following command:

`ubuntu-bug xorg`

This should collect all the required information and you should be given the chance to add in more information about your situation and what you've done to try and fix the issue.